# Can't find linker symbol for virtual table for `Preferences'

Tags: c++, qt

I'm working on some database aplication, and I've found something that stoped me for days.
As above debuger says:

> can't find linker symbol for virtual table for `Preferences' value found>`Ui_MainWindow::setupUi(QMainWindow*)::{lambda()#13}::operator()() const::qstring_literal' instead

And my code is below:
MainWindow.cpp, just one method:

```
QString MainWindow::ConnectDatabase()
{
    // TODO Make Alaviability to change Database things
    QSqlDatabase database = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QMYSQL");
    Preferences pref;
    std::vector <QString> preferencesVector = pref.openFromFile();

    database.setHostName(preferencesVector[1]);
    database.setDatabaseName(preferencesVector[2]);
    database.setUserName(preferencesVector[3]);
    database.setPassword(preferencesVector[4]);
    if (database.isValid())
    {
        database.open();
        return "Połączono!\n";
    }
    else
      return "Database Error: " + database.lastError().text();
}
```

And preferences class in preferences.cpp:

```
Preferences::Preferences(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Preferences)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Preferences::~Preferences()
{
    delete ui;
}

std::fstream Preferences::openFile()
{
    std::fstream preferencesFile;
    preferencesFile.open("preferencesFile.txt");
    return preferencesFile;
}

std::vector<QString> Preferences::openFromFile()
{
    std::string line;
    std::vector <QString> preferencesVector;
    std::fstream preferencesFile = openFile();
    if (preferencesFile.is_open())
    {
        while (std::getline(preferencesFile, line))
            preferencesVector.push_back(QString::fromStdString(line));
    }
    return preferencesVector;
}

void Preferences::saveIntoFile()
{
    std::fstream preferencesFile = openFile();
    if (preferencesFile.is_open())
    {
        preferencesFile << ui->lineEditHos;
        preferencesFile << ui->lineEditDatabase;
        preferencesFile << ui->lineEditUser;
        preferencesFile << ui->lineEditPassword;
        QMessageBox::information(NULL, "Informacja", "Plik z ustawieniami został zapisany", QMessageBox::Ok);
    }
    else
        QMessageBox::warning(NULL, "UWAGA!", "Plik z ustawieniami nie został otwarty", QMessageBox::Ok);
    preferencesFile.close();
}
bool Preferences::on_pushButtonOk_clicked()
{
    saveIntoFile();
    this->close();
    return true;
}
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: I think you need to provide more context. For example, I cannot see the declaration (i.e. `class Preferences {..};`) of the class "Preferences". Try for a [mcve].

Comment: Why the sql tag?

Comment: Usually, linker errors like this are explained by how you compile.  In particular, your error message strongly suggests the use of `uic` - how do you ensure that the UI is compiled and linked?

Comment: Check if your class declaration has the `Q_OBJECT` macro at the beginning of it (you need it). Then make sure to do a clean, rerun qmake and rebuild.